# Math operations on multi-dimensional Python dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

I am porting over some code from PHP that iterates through some database results and builds a two-dimensional array of wins and losses for teams in a baseball league. Here's the code in question in PHP

```
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $home_team = $result['Game']['home_team_id'];
        $away_team = $result['Game']['away_team_id'];

        if (!isset($wins[$home_team][$away_team])) $wins[$home_team][$away_team] = 0;
        if (!isset($wins[$away_team][$home_team])) $wins[$away_team][$home_team] = 0;
        if (!isset($losses[$home_team][$away_team])) $losses[$home_team][$away_team] = 0;
        if (!isset($losses[$away_team][$home_team])) $losses[$away_team][$home_team] = 0;

        if ($result['Game']['home_score'] > $result['Game']['away_score']) {
            $wins[$home_team][$away_team]++;
            $losses[$away_team][$home_team]++;
        } else {
            $wins[$away_team][$home_team]++;
            $losses[$home_team][$away_team]++;
        }
    }
```

`$results` is an array that contains the results of a database query

(Edited to add the Python code I have in-profess)

Now I have this but in Python. `results` contains a collection of Sqlalchemy result objects

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, create_engine, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('postgresql://stats:st@ts=Fun@localhost/ibl_stats')
Session = sessionmaker()
Session.configure(bind=engine)
session = Session()


class Game(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'games'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    week = Column(Integer)
    home_score = Column(Integer)
    away_score = Column(Integer)
    home_team_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('franchises.id'))
    away_team_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('franchises.id'))


class Franchise(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'franchises'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    nickname = Column(String(3))
    name = Column(String(50))
    conference = Column(String(10))
    division = Column(String(10))
    ip = Column(Integer)

# Loop through our standings building up the breakdown results
results = session.query(Game).all()
wins = dict()
losses = dict()

for result in results:
    home_team = result.home_team_id
    away_team = result.away_team_id

    if result.home_score > result.away_score:
        wins[home_team][away_team] += 1
        losses[away_team][home_team] += 1
    else:
        wins[away_team][home_team] += 1
        losses[home_team][away_team] += 1
```

So when I run this code I get the following error:

```
(venv)vagrant@ibl:/vagrant/scripts$ python playoff_odds.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "playoff_odds.py", line 45, in <module>
    wins[home_team][away_team] += 1
KeyError: 1
```

I did some searching before and it starts getting into the concept of "autovivification", which is something PHP does by default but Python does not.

So how do I duplicate the same behaviour in the Python code?

Comment: I'd start by writing some Python. Python nested dicts can be accessed in exactly the same way as you are doing in your PHP. `$result['Game']['home_team_id']` would be simply `result['Game']['home_team_id']` in Python. Why not have a go yourself. If you get stuck on a particular problem, *then* would be the time to ask for help.

Comment: In other words, please try something first :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I forgot to add in the Python version of what I'm working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Python's built-in dict class can be subclassed to implement autovivificious dictionaries simply by overriding the **missing**() method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification#Python) , but that's only part of the solution. If you were to simply implement the `Tree` example in the Wikipedia link and do something like:

```
wins = Tree()

wins['team_a']['team_b'] += 1
```

You'd run into: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'Tree' and 'int'` because the `wins['team_a']['team_b']` example code will have automatically been typed `Tree` as well.

Whereas:

```
wins = Tree()

wins['team_a']['team_b'] = 1
```

would assign the value 1 properly (as it's a reassignment, not an operation on an existing typed value).

The solution would subclassing to implement autovivification *and* ensuring that the leaf elements are integers that you can operate on.

The following should help, or at least get you started:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def autovivify(levels=1, final=dict):
    return (defaultdict(final) if levels < 2
        else defaultdict(lambda: autovivify(levels - 1, final)))

wins = autovivify(2, int)
losses = autovivify(2, int)

wins['team_a']['team_b'] += 1
losses['team_b']['team_a'] += 1

wins['team_b']['team_c'] += 1
losses['team_c']['team_b'] += 1

wins['team_a']['team_c'] += 1
losses['team_c']['team_a'] += 1

wins['team_a']['team_b'] += 1
losses['team_b']['team_a'] += 1

print(wins['team_a']) # outputs defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'team_b': 2, 'team_c': 1})
```

**Source:** http://blogs.fluidinfo.com/terry/2012/05/26/autovivification-in-python-nested-defaultdicts-with-a-specific-final-type/

The autovivify function will ensure that the first assignment (`team_a`) will give you another autovivifying tree, and the second (`team_b`) will give you an integer. From there, your `+= 1` will continue to increment the initial value of `0`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would probably use namedtuples here, but it's hard to tell from just this snippet.

If you'd like material on how to write more Pythonic code, I recommend checking out Raymond Hettinger's videos, particularly

"Best practices for beautiful intelligible code" and
"Transforming Code into Beautiful, Idiomatic Python":

http://pyvideo.org/speaker/raymond-hettinger.html

Answer (score 1):

This question has many interpretations. For example I would simulate results with the following dictionary:

```
>>> result = {'Game':{'home_team':{'score':20,'id':1}, 'away_team':{'score':15,'id':2}}}
>>> print result['Game']
{'home_team': {'score': 20, 'id': 1}, 'away_team': {'score': 15, 'id': 2}}
>>> print result['Game']['home_team']
{'score': 20, 'id': 1}
>>> print result['Game']['away_team']['score']
15
```

There are a lot of ways to simulate your code, the above is just one of them. Of course the code doesn't do what the php code does, just shows a way to access the data.